# Unfortunately, Process has stopped

Tags: boot, bugs

Ok so guys I'm getting kinda irritated by this problem. It is telling me `Unfortunately, <process> has stopped`. Meaning, when I go to launcher, it says `Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped`; to Google, `Unfortunately, Google has stopped`; and so on. How in the world do I fix this?  I can't go on the launcher or settings or anything.

I wiped cache but no luck. What should I do? Maybe Restore User Data?

Comment: I have wiped the factory/reset data. Now i will have to see to what it does..

Comment: Wiping the data should probably do it, but you might need to re-flash the ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory reset will resolve this issue! To get to that option though you have to be in recovery mode. To boot to recovery mode press the <kbd>power</kbd> button and <kbd>volume up</kbd> button simultaneously! And then you will get this screen:

[image: Boot Mode]

Then just reset to factory version and it should work!

Answer (score -1):

You should wipe data, system, etc but not internal storage. Then you should reinstall your ROM. You may want to back the data up via titanium backup or another tool. I wouldn't recommend a nandroid backup.